# "Unable to determine the principal end of an association..." error when adding multiple entities of the same type

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework

We have an MVC 4 project, and recently some changes were made to database schema that might be related to this issue.  Please excuse the Hungarian Notation.

There are several relevant database tables:

`mtblPersonRole` is 1:M with `tblMemberBenefit`, which is 1:M with `tblSourceDeduction`

Now, there is a process where I create new `tblMemberBenefit` entity(ies) and point them to the same `mtblPersonRole` entity.  Each `tblMemberBenefit` might have one or more `tblSourceDeduction` entities as child(ren).

If I only add a single `tblMemberBenefit`, then everything is fine.  However, if I add 2 or more of them, then Entity Framework chokes and throws an exception:

```
System.Data.UpdateException Unable to determine the principal end of the 'REIS_beModel.FK_tblSourceDeduction_tblMemberBenefit' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key. Void RegisterEntityReferentialConstraints(System.Data.IEntityStateEntry, Boolean)    at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.RegisterEntityReferentialConstraints(IEntityStateEntry stateEntry, Boolean currentValues)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.RegisterReferentialConstraints(IEntityStateEntry stateEntry)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.PullModifiedEntriesFromStateManager()
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.ProduceCommands()
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
```

This happens regardless of whether or not there are actually any `tblSourceDeduction` entities involved, and it never happens when I only add a single `tblMemberBenefit`.  All tables have an "Id" column that is 32-bit integer and `Identity`, so I don't think the issue is anything to do with that.

If I call `SaveChanges()` on the `DbContext` before adding the 2nd `tblMemberBenefit`, then everything is fine.  However, this is not an acceptable solution, because I need to do all of this inside a transaction, and roll everything back if anything fails.

Any ideas why I am getting this exception, and how I can prevent it from occurring?

Comment: try validating your model, quite possible that there is a difference between store and conceptual models or mapping between those..

Comment: could you please show the code you use to add entities? do you use `Add` for adding new entity and `Attach` for attaching existing ones?

Comment: The process is pretty complicated and spans probably 10 or 12 different methods, depending on what is being done.  I use `Add` for adding new entities, and nothing is ever `Attach`ed (and shouldn't need to be since everything happens within the same `DbContext` instance).

Comment: `GetValidationErrors` returns 0 errors.  Here's where it gets really interesting: if I give either of the POCO entities a "fake" Id value (I used -1 in this case), then everything works.

Comment: indeed, what value does that Id has before you set negative value? Should be 0, meaning new entity...

Comment: They all have 0, unless I explicitly set some other value.  However, when I leave it at 0, the `SaveChanges` call throws the exception.

Comment: Could you please have a look at Associations in your Model Browser Window and find the corresponding relationship details `FK_tblSourceDeduction_tblMemberBenefit`. Maybe there's something wrong, like someone set it to be 1-to-1 relation.

Comment: It looks okay to me.  1:M with `tblMemberBenefit` being the 1 side.

Comment: strange...there's some inconsistency...can you try deleting your entity from the model and then update your model by adding the table again...(unless you don't have your code under source control)

Comment: does your entity has auto incremented primary key in the database? maybe not and you simply insert two entities with the same primary key equal to 0?

Comment: The PK columns are set to `IDENTITY` in the database.  Just removed all 3 entities and re-added them to conceptual model, and nothing changed.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fd547161-12f7-4c91-a5ce-b5431dbf86c9/unable-to-determine-the-principal-end-of-foreign-key-name-relationship-multiple-added-entities?forum=adodotnetentityframework I think this guy had similar issue...sorry I'm out of thoughts ((

Comment: Correct.  And the negative Id also seems to work for him.  I just don't understand why it worked before with all Id columns set to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody has posted an answer yet, I will post what I did that seems to have worked:

First, I created an `Enum` to represent an offset for each of the `tblMemberBenefit` entities (they are unique by a `BenefitType` property, meaning that I will only ever add one of a particular benefit type).  Then, when I create the POCO, I set the Id column to the negative value for whatever the offset `Enum` is for that given type.  So the first type might have an Id of -1, while the next type has an Id of -4.

Now, when I call `SaveChanges()`, everything works as expected and the negative Id columns get changed to identity values given by SQL.